# Azure Test Plans

Tags: azure, azure-functions, test-plan

I am  MSFT rookie and QA so please excuse me in my questions and those may sound silly.

I have Basic Azure Devops Plan

I can see that I have access to Test Run tab but don't have access to Create a new Test Plan

I can see that I can create test cases by creating item in Board Tab and then can see them In Test Plan tab

Now I don't understand and I am completely on the fence

If I don't have test plan subscription how in the earth I am able to create test cases for board times and then can see them in Test Plan tab but can't create a new test plan....

I can't even add configurations

Can't even create test run

I am confused as in why only half features are working? I don't see a proper page about plans

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone mate!

Back in time, I was able to create URL based performance test etc via Azure DevOps. I moved to another company which they use TeamCity and Octopus Deploy for their pipelines. I had worked there for more than 1 year and when I tried to create test cases on my side project recently I was also trying to understand the same situation. Because I couldn't! I thought there is a glitch on the Azure DevOps test page on the first sight. Then I realised that the feature I was using has been moved to another pricing tier https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/

So if you'd like to use test plans, you need to purchase Basic + Test Plans User License.

[image]
*Figure 1: This is the screen that I see on Test Plans page.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/new-test-plans-page?view=azure-devops

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks bud... appreciate it my friend but why the heck i am able to create test case from board tab? Like now that i am able to create this what special do u think we hve basic + test plan

Comment: I don't follow mate. On your original question, you said: "I can see that I have access to Test Run tab but don't have access to Create a new Test Plan" and now you are saying you can? Can you provide some screenshots, please?